# Move folders only with mv

Tags: directory, mv

I have a folder containing files and folders.

```
folder/file1.jpg
folder/file2.jpg
folder/file3.jpg
folder/subfolder1/file1.txt
folder/subfolder1/file2.txt
folder/subfolder2/file1.txt
folder/subfolder3/
destination/
```

I want to move all folders (and their content)  in a new folder, but not the files.

Eg.

```
folder/file1.jpg
folder/file2.jpg
folder/file3.png
destination/subfolder1/file1.txt
destination/subfolder1/file2.txt
destination/subfolder2/file1.txt
destination/subfolder3/
```

I know that, if I wanted to select all of my jpeg files (for example), I would do `mv folder/*.jpg destination`. But what is the command to select all folders?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For that, you just need to include a aditional / at end of * like that:

```
mv folder/*.jpg destination (match only jpg files) 
mv folder/* destination (match anything found)
mv folder/*/ destination  (match only the folders)
```

This will move only the folders inside "folder" to the destination, and not the files inside "folder" (note that the files in subfolders, are moved).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the actual directory names you can use this

```
mv folder/subfolder* destination/
```

If there is no pattern (`subfolder*`) to match the folder names you could do this

```
find folder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mv {} destination/ \;
```

or even this

```
find folder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mv -t destination/ {} +
```

Comment: Ok thank you ! That is what I was looking for. Can you please explain what `\;` is for in the end of the first `find` example ?

Comment: @cdrom It tells `find` where the command line to execute with `-exec` ends.  The `+` in the second `find` serves the same purpose, but has different semantics. See the `find` manual.

Answer (score 0):

If the subfolders have uniform names, you may use [roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439759/116858).  If not, you may use a simple shell loop:

```
mkdir -p destination
for name in folder/*; do
    [ ! -d "$name" ] && continue
    mv "$name" destination
done
```

This would loop over all directory entries in `folder` (files and directories alike), test each one for whether it's a directory or not, and move them if they are.

Another possibility is to use `find`:

```
mkdir -p destination
find folder -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mv {} destination ';'
```

This would find all pathnames of all directories in `folder` (but not below, and not the directory `folder` itself), and move each found directory to `destination`.